# Why does the lookup of my managed bean fail?

Tags: ejb, cdi, jndi

Consider the following code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <title>Crear Personas</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view>


        <h:form>
            <h1><h:outputText value="Create/Edit"/></h1>
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel value="Perid:" for="perid" />
                <h:inputText id="perid" value="#{lineaControl.persona.perid}" title="Perid" required="true" requiredMessage="The Perid field is required."/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Pernombre:" for="pernombre" />
                <h:inputText id="pernombre" value="#{lineaControl.persona.pernombre}" title="Pernombre" required="true" requiredMessage="The Pernombre field is required."/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Perapellido:" for="perapellido" />
                <h:inputText id="perapellido" value="#{lineaControl.persona.perapellido}" title="Perapellido" required="true" requiredMessage="The Perapellido field is required."/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Pertelefonofijo:" for="pertelefonofijo" />
                <h:inputText id="pertelefonofijo" value="#{lineaControl.persona.pertelefonofijo}" title="Pertelefonofijo" required="true" requiredMessage="The Pertelefonofijo field is required."/>
                <h:outputLabel value="Perfechanacimiento:" for="perfechanacimiento" />
                <h:inputText id="perfechanacimiento" value="#{lineaControl.persona.perfechanacimiento}" title="Perfechanacimiento" required="true" requiredMessage="The Perfechanacimiento field is required.">
                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="MM/dd/yyyy" />
                </h:inputText>
                <h:outputLabel value="Percedula:" for="percedula" />
                <h:inputText id="percedula" value="#{lineaControl.persona.percedula}" title="Percedula" required="true" requiredMessage="The Percedula field is required."/>
            </h:panelGrid>
             <h:commandButton value="Crear" action="#{personaControl.crearPersona()}" ></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </f:view>


</h:body>
</html>
```

This one is the view:

```
@Named(value = "personaControl")
@SessionScoped
public class PersonaControl implements Serializable {

/**
 * Creates a new instance of PersonaControl
 */
public PersonaControl() {

    persona = new Persona();
}
@EJB

private Persona persona;

PersonaFacade personaFacade;

public Persona getPersona() {
    return persona;
}

public void setPersona(Persona persona) {
    this.persona = persona;
}



public List<Persona> listarPersonas(){

    return personaFacade.findAll();
}

public void crearPersona(){

    personaFacade.create(persona);
    persona = new Persona();
}

public void eliminarPersona(Persona newPersona){

    persona = newPersona;
    personaFacade.remove(persona);
    persona = new Persona();

}

public String editarPersona(Persona newPersona){

    persona = newPersona;
    return "/Equipo/Editar";
}

public String editarPersona(){
    personaFacade.edit(persona);
    persona = new Persona();
    return "/Equipo/Editar";
}
}
```

This one is the controller:

Entity and facade were generated using the NetBeans IDE, so when I try to create the new user, I get this error output:

> Exception attempting to inject Remote ejb-ref name=controlador.PersonaControl/persona,Remote 3.x interface =entidades.Persona,ejb-link=null,lookup=,mappedName=,jndi-name=entidades.Persona,refType=Session into class controlador.PersonaControl: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/controlador.PersonaControl/persona' in SerialContext[myEnv={java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming}

I cannot understand why I am getting this error output. I can't create any user.

Comment: Why are you creating `new Persona()` in the constructor, and *also* asking for it to be injected by annotating `persona` with `@EJB`? --- If code gets past that point, how are you expecting any calls on `personaFacade` to not fail with `NullPointerException`, given that you never assign a value to it?

Comment: Most likely Persona is not an ejb (and it should not be)